# Django admin custom form doesn't reflect in server

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In django admin I need to upload multiple file. So customise `change_form.html`. This changes working nice in my local environment. But do not work in server.
in `change_form.html`

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block inline_field_sets %}
{% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
    {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
{% endfor %}

<fieldset class="module">
  <h2>Upload Photos</h2>
  <input name="bundle_images" type="file" multiple />
</fieldset>
{% endblock %}
```

in `admin.py`

```
class ImageBundleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form = 'templates/admin/imagebundles/ImageBundle/change_form.html'
    .....
    .....
```

The output in my local

[image: Upload option show]

But output in my server

[image: No upload button show]

Please advice what I miss? In server I used nginx and gunicorn

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `change_form.html` available in server?

Comment: yes ... I checked